# How to force the www prefix to load js file

Tags: javascript, css, .htaccess

I have a script on my website that is opencart. the problem is that js file not working with www. prefix for eg. if i write in browse www.example.com the js file not load but with example.com without WWW all things is fine .
The other problem is that the Hoster is disable .htaccess file for security reason.
does any help without .htaccess file .

Comment: Did you try to specify the full working path in the src of this script call? something like : <script type="text/javascript" src="http ://example.com/path/myscript.js"></script>

Comment: after search i found this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24851890/how-to-configure-opencart-live-site-dynamically
it help me it is awesome

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a problem with the website configuration and may want to work with your hosting provider. Other options could be that you may have to hard code paths to the one without the www in front of it, or if you can write some PHP or something server-side to take the domain name and strip the "www.".

```
<?php $url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_SCHEME"] . "://" . str_replace("www.", "", $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]) . "/path/to/file.js"; ?>
<script src="<?php echo $url ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```